# IE prompts to open or save json result from server

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Internet explorer in compatibility mode gets the data from the server in an ajax callback method, and pops-up a dialog if I want to save the data or open. How to get rid of that?

client says:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: $("#UIdlgHolder > form").serialize(),
        url: $("#UIdlgHolder > form").attr("action"),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            {
                alert(data.message);
            }
}
```

server answers:

```
return new JsonResult { Data = new { result = false, message = "Yay!" } };
```

Comment: What is the content type of the return?

Comment: This isn't specific to ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC3, or jQuery; hence it's a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943439/json-response-download-in-ie710).

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30180509/2305243)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like this SO question may be relevant to you:

[How can I convince IE to simply display Application json rather than offer to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483771/how-can-i-convince-ie-to-simply-display-application-json-rather-than-offer-to-dow)

If not:

Have you tried setting the dataType expected in the ajax options? i.e. dataType: 'json'

Have you tried other content types such as 'application/json' or 'text/javascript'

Comment: solution requires each user to run a regex hack... not useful for production web apps.

Answer (score 36):

Even though it's not supposedly the correct way, setting the content type to text/html made IE deal with this correctly for me:

```
return Json(result, "text/html");
```

Works in all the version that F12 tools gives you in IE9.

Comment: It's not the correct way.  There is no "supposedly" about it.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I had no control over the ajax request (third-party control) and IE9 would *not* work. So even if it isn't the correct way, it still works (with no problems on other browsers so far)

Comment: Its annoying, but correct. I had a form that i was capturing the Submit() event on and firing AJAX to get a JSON response, and IE kept stupidly trying to Open/Save the JSON response in the background! This cleared it up, at the cost of loosing the nice JSON formatting in Firefox when viewing that URL directly.

Comment: The reason this is wrong is that angle brackets, which are valid within JSON, result in the browser treating the JSON as mal-formed HTML

Comment: Thanks alot. After wasting 6 hrs i just did this. my bluimp file upload working awesome now on IE9 too. Thanks again.

Comment: Bit late to the party, but one more note - this appears to only be an issue in IE9 (and below) when the form is multipart/form-data. So you can avoid setting incorrect headers except in that circumstance.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty is correct.  A better alternative would be `"text/plain"`.

Answer (score 32):

If using MVC, one way of handling this is to implement a base controller in which you *override* (hide) the Json(object) method as follows:

```
public class ExtendedController : Controller
{
    protected new JsonResult Json(object data)
    {
        if (!Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json"))
            return base.Json(data, "text/plain");
        else
            return base.Json(data);
    }
}
```

Now, your controllers can all inherit ExtendedController and simply call `return Json(model);` ...

- without modifying the response content type for those browsers which play nicely (not <=IE9 !)
- without having to remember to use `Json(data, "text/plain")` in your various Ajax action methods

This works with json requests which would otherwise display the "Open or Save" message in IE8 & IE9 such as those made by [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Comment: Thanks Timothy, glad you like it! (It's saved so much pain in our projects).

Comment: Perfect, just perfect!

Comment: i need same solution in web api, can you help me?

Comment: I found using "text/plain" would return the json wrapped in '<pre></pre>' tags. Using "text/html" instead of "text/plain" fixed the issue.

Comment: This solution has problems. For example, Chrome issues the blanket `AcceptTypes` of `*/*`, which this solution doesn't catch, and so Chrome ends up getting sent `text/plain`, which is incorrect.

Comment: What worked for me is check the browser type before sending the type back

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to send your ajax request using POST method ?
You could also try to set content type to 'text/x-json' while returning result from the server.

Comment: tell me, on which IE ( version 6,7,8,9, 10 test ) it fails on this request.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the content-type to "text/html" instead of "application/json" server side before returning the response. Described it in a blog post, where other solutions have also been added:

http://blog.degree.no/2012/09/jquery-json-ie8ie9-treats-response-as-downloadable-file/

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this is just another annoying quirk of using Internet Explorer.

[image]

The simple solution is to run a small .reg file on your PC, to tell IE to *automatically* open .json files, rather than nag about whether to open/save it.

I've put a copy of the file you'll need here:

[JSON mime type](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/SampleCode/MakeIEshowJSONdata.zip)

You'll need to have Admin rights to run this.

Comment: (Why did 2 people vote down this answer...?  You *do* need to install a small registry change to get IE to automatically open JSON data, when you call a service from jQuery, rather than asking to save it, and no one else offered this suggestion....  I thought my answer was really useful.  I lose faith in StackOverflow sometimes....)

Answer (score 1):

Is above javascript code the one you're using in your web application ?
If so - i would like to point few errors in it:
firstly - it has an additional '{' sign in definition of 'success' callback function
secondly - it has no ')' sign after definition of ajax callback.
Valid code should look like:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: 'args',
        url: '@Url.Action("PostBack")',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(data.message);
            }
    });
```

try using above code - it gave me 'Yay' alert on all 3 IE versions ( 7,8,9 ).

Answer (score 1):

I faced this while using [jQuery FileUpload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

Then I took a look in their documentation, most exactly in the [Content-Type Negotiation section](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup#content-type-negotiation) and followed their suggestion for **Ruby/Rails**.

```
render(json: <some-data>, content_type: request.format)
```

Which fixed the issue for me.

**Quick Explanation**: for old IE/Opera versions, this plugin will use an iframe with `text/plain` or `text/html` content-type, so if you force the response to `json`, browser will try download it. Using the same content-type as in the request will make it work for any browser.

Comment: That's the effing answer right here! Thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, IE11 seems to behave that way when there is some JS syntax error in the console (doesn't matter where exactly) and `dataType: 'json'` has no effect at all.