# jQuery-File-Upload and Spring MVC IE9 doesn't work

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, file-upload

I use [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and Spring MVC like server part. I try [the example](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) and it doesn't work in the IE 9  browser. It says to me: "would you like to save or open the object"

Client is like in the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/fileUpload/1" multiple>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

And server is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "fileUpload/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public FileUploadResultDTO upload(MultipartFile file,
                                      @PathVariable Long id,
                                      Locale locale,
                                      HttpServletRequest request) {
        FileUploadResultDTO resultDTO = new FileUploadResultDTO();
        // Logic saving file and return back response like object
        return resultDTO;
    }

public class FileUploadResultDTO {
    private Long photoId;
    private String pathToPhoto;
    private String pathToSmallPhoto;

// getters/setters
}
```

It works in all browsers except IE

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and managed to solve it by changing the method to always produce 'text/plain' content instead of 'application/json'. I did this by adding 'produces="text/plain"' to request mapping annotation, changing the return value type to String and converting the object manually to Json using Jackson.

With your code this would look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "fileUpload/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="text/plain")
@ResponseBody
public String upload(MultipartFile file,
                                  @PathVariable Long id,
                                  Locale locale,
                                  HttpServletRequest request) {
    FileUploadResultDTO resultDTO = new FileUploadResultDTO();
    // Logic saving file and return back response like object
    return Jackson.toJsonString(resultDTO);
}
```

This seems to work for both IE9 (that uses the iframe transport) and modern browsers that do not, but seems as bit hackish,as the correct type should be 'application/json'.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like this:

[IE prompts to open or save json result from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114360/stupid-ie-prompts-to-open-or-save-json-result-which-comes-from-server)

hope it helps

Comment: It doesn't help me :( I've tried to change all possible metatypes, no results.

Comment: @Andrew, can you specify what exactly you did that helped?