# Change content-type in Spring MVC for file upload in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, spring-mvc, file-upload, content-type, blueimp

I use the blueimp jQuery File Upload (UI version) 7.2.1 with a Java Spring MVC 3.1 backend.
It works fine for chrome and FF. Unfortunately not for IE because of the content-type="application/json". The recommendation is to change this with content negotiation via accept headers. I know that there is a Spring ContentNegotiatingViewResolver. Is that the appropriate approach to fix this? Has anybody solved this problem so far?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by changing the Spring MVC controller to produce 'text/plain' instead of 'application/json'. Details in my answer here: [jQuery-File-Upload and Spring MVC IE9 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024952/jquery-file-upload-and-spring-mvc-ie9-doesnt-work/19701539#19701539) 
This worked fine but I would also be interested in a proper way of doing this, as this seems a bit hackish.