# Web API IE9 JSON Data “do you want to open or save this file”

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First off, please understand that I am not trying to view JSON in IE9. I use Fiddler all the time. I have a third party uploader called Fine Uploader that expects JSON response messages upon successful Ajax file uploads.

Now I understand that IE9 does not have a MIME to display JSON but I am NOT trying to display JSON. I am just returning a JSON response after ajax uploading some files and IE9 attempts to open my ajax response.

Since I intend to have all my Web API responses formatted in JSON do I have to add a custom text/html response content-type for every api call to make my application compatible with IE9? Seriously ridiculous stuff, I can't get over how much time I waste dealing with IE compatibility issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although Ray's answer works, this changes the response content type for all Json respones. Ideally, we shouldn't affect the response type for browsers which play nicely.

For an easy way to resolve this (particularly in MVC) see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114360/stupid-ie-prompts-to-open-or-save-json-result-which-comes-from-server#15910942).

In short, the following code does the trick, and can be wrapped into a base controller / helper method if applicable:

```
if (!Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json"))
    return base.Json(data, "text/plain");
else
    return base.Json(data);
```

I hope that helps someone else!

Answer (score 4):

In WebAPI, you can set the global response in the configs that are fired in the Global.asax. This way all your browsers treat your WebAPI responses as true JSON.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // stuff...

        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
            .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Most important... +++++++++++++
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
            .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        // -------------------------------

        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your response's content-type: it must be "text/plain", NOT "application/json".

Comment: Microsoft's web API is setting the content-type to application/json. I am returning json, why would I set the content-type to text/plain? To appease IE9?

Comment: I changed my content-type to text/html, I am sure text/plain works too. I try to Vote Up your answer but my reputation is not high enough to do so, thanks for your help.

Comment: You can always "accept" my answer.  If my advice has helped, please do so.  As far as text/html vs text/plain, the latter is generally the safest content-type for your response.  Either are fine, unless you plan on returning HTML in your JSON response.  In that case, text/plain is the content-type you will want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect people to consume your API using IE9? Usually, people with browsers can't read JSON anyhow. I suggest you test your API using something like Fiddler2.

The reason IE9 prompts you to download the file is because it doesn't have a MIME handler to display it. Browsers are designed to display certain mime types only, like text/html, text/xml, image/png, image/jpeg, etc. You usually need a special plugin to display custom types like application/pdf. JSON, with its application/json mime type is no different.

If it really bugs you that much, read [this](http://banachowski.com/deprogramming/2011/04/viewing-json-in-ie9/) and [this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Apr/01/Displaying-JSON-in-your-Browser).

Comment: Well that is thing, I am not trying to read/view the JSON, I am returning JSON to a third party file uploader called Fine Uploader. It requires JSON formatted messages to display a successful upload ({"success" = true}). So the consumer is Fine Uploader aka some client side Javascript and IE9 is opening the JSON message meant for Fine Uploader. This is an Ajax call by the way. So on initial load the mime type is text/html