# IE prompts to open or save json result which comes from server

Tags: json, spring, internet-explorer, blueimp

I am using blueimp fileupload plugin which works fine in chrome,although same is not working in IE less then IE10.I am getting a prompts to open or save json result.After searching i tried few solution. like one here:-https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup#content-type-negotiation ,but no luck.

I am using Spring3.1,AngularJS.
with my 1st approach i am able to upload file,although getting prompts to open or save json in IE as result also

```
Content-Type   application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

output Json returned is

```
ExcelUpload={UnprocessedRequests=12,AcceptedRequests=0, processedFlag=T,RejectedRequests=0,result=Excel_13}
```

Spring code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveExcel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> saveExcelDetails(@RequestParam(value="file",required=false) MultipartFile file,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> excelUpload = myService.saveExcelDetails(request,file);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");     
    return excelUpload;
}
```

then i tried 2nd approach

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveExcel", method = RequestMethod.POST,**produces = "text/html"**)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> saveExcelDetails(@RequestParam(value="file",required=false) MultipartFile file,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> excelUpload = myService.saveExcelDetails(request,file);     
    return excelUpload;
}
```

but getting error as "**Could not find acceptable representation**"
am i missing something here

> Iframe based uploads require a Content-type of text/plain or text/html for the JSON response - they will show an undesired download dialog if the iframe response is set to application/json.we can make use of the Accept header to offer different content types for the file upload response.

how can i achieve

> to make use of the Accept header to offer different content types for the file upload response.

in my scenario(code).

Eric i changed it as you suggested

```
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object>saveExcelDetails(@RequestParam(value="file",required=false) MultipartFile file,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestHeader(value="Accept") String accept) throws Exception {
Map<String, Object> excelUpload = myService.saveExcelDetails(request,file);
   if (accept.indexOf("application/json") != -1) {         
        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    } else {           
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
    }
return excelUpload;
```

}

done setting response content type as "text/plain", also to the response Header still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try below codes:

```
<beans:bean id="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: This works for me. With one exception - i've used 'text/plain' not 'text/html'.

Answer (score 0):

By design, IE will prompt the user to save a file if you navigate a frame to a URL that returns `Content-Type: application/json` as IE does not offer a native view for JSON.

In your server side code, you can examine the request's `Accept` header. If it doesn't contain `application/json` then you should return `text/plain` instead.

Comment: thanks EircLaw, returning `text/plain` you mean `setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`.

Comment: That looks like it would do it. You could confirm with Fiddler or another network debugger.

Comment: done something like                     `response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8"); response.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain; charset=UTF-8");`         still getting Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8 in IE

Comment: It'd probably be best to update the code in the original question to show your full code block, including your "if" test, etc.

Comment: I don't know what "still no luck" means. When you watch the response to IE using Fiddler, what's the Content-Type?

Comment: In response Header
i am getting `Content-Type application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the @ResponseBody annotation, I think that the content type gets reset to application/json after you set it to text/plain. The JacksonMessageConverter might have something to do with it.

I see in Fiddler2 that IE8 is **not** sending application/json in its Accept: header. At the server side, I check the Accept header if it contains application/json. (Btw I just use "contains()" rather than the clunky "IndexOf") and replace it with text/plain if application/json isn't in the Accept: header.

But sure enough, the response Fiddler2 gets to see states that it has a Content-Type header of 'application/json'.

So something is resetting the Content-Type, *after* I reset it to be text/plain.

I'm about to try this: http://incomplete-code.blogspot.be/2012/08/spring-mvc-internet-explorer-7-and-json.html

Answer (score 0):

IE actually does a MIME detection if  `header("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");` were not set, and overwritten the servers response to IE detected format. For example, a JSON response with `text/html` header will be overwritten with `text/javascript` for security purpose.

Reference:

1. [MIME Type Detection in Windows Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. [Handling MIME Types in Windows Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. [Handling MIME Types in Windows Internet Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787872(v=ws.10).aspx)
4. [Wiki: MIME Sniffing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_sniffing)

Comment: Currently, #3 (above) is dead; however, WayBack has it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150914105434/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787872%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) from September 14, 2015, under the title 'Internet Explorer MIME Handling Enforcement'.