# Unable to Upload file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I am trying upload a file(pdf/doc) type  from iE 9 to server using jquery fileupload plugin , but when response from server is returned of type json object , IE is prompting me to open/save that file.
I get this as a pop at the bottom  of the IE 9, Not sure how to get ride of it.

Exact message is "do you want to  open or save file from localhost".

Comment: Check the content type from your server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114360/stupid-ie-prompts-to-open-or-save-json-result-which-comes-from-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the problem in the past.  The best solution i found wast to 
a. serialize your response as JSON, and return the json as plain, instead of json, then convert the return string to a json object when it gets back to the client.

Very possibly a better way to handle it, but this is what I have done int the past.