# jQuery ajax issue on IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-9

I am using [this](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) plugin to let users upload images trough ajax.

To create the uploader and trigger a post this jQuery function is used:

```
function createUploader() {
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
             element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
             allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
             multiple: false,
             action: '@Url.Action("AjaxUpload", "Upload")',
             onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
               window.location.href = responseJSON.message;
            }
        });
    }
```

Well, in `responseJSON.message` I am returning the path where the file was uploaded (actually converted) and I am doing a trick with `window.location.href` to force the browser to show the user DOWNLOAD box for that file.

This works great on FF and Chrome but on IE it says:

`Do you want to open or save AjaxUpload from localhost?`

And if you press open, instead of getting the file from the specified location, you actually get a file containing responseJSON message.

Any jQuery guru who can give me a clue for this issue?

**UPDATE**: What I can confirm is that the issue is not with `window.location.href = responseJSON.message;` because even if I remove this line and put `alert('something')` the same problems occurs...so instead of parsing `onComplete`, IE try to open the JSON response...

Comment: What's the point of uploading and then downloading the same file? Or are you doing some transformation on it on the server?

Comment: yeah, it's a conversion I'm doing: from pdf to word

Comment: Does your route translate the ActionMethod pointer correctly ? If look through IE source, what does it show ?
Also, what's the return type on AjaxUpload method ?

Comment: Also.. I'm not familiar with that uploader but if there is a OnFailure event try using that and display the error.

Comment: I'm returning a `JsonResult`: `return new JsonResult { Data = new { message = outputFilePathResponse } };` so the response is for instance: `{"message":"/Tmp/0c40d994-6d3e-4fab-a43f-028468cb77e8.doc"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
return Json(new { Data = new { message = outputFilePathResponse } }, "text/html");
```

Reference:
[IE tries to download JSON in ASP. NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591998/ie-tries-to-download-json-in-asp-net-mvc-3)