# parse JSON response in IE9

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 web app I'm using FineUploader to upload files.

When a file is uploaded I send a json response from my controller like so:

```
return this.Json(packageUploadResult, "text/plain", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

I had to modify "application/json" to "text/plain" because I was getting "Save As" "Open" options in IE [(info here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388893/ie9-json-data-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file). ONLY IN IE. It works fine in all other browsers.

View:

```
...
        }).on('complete', function (event, id, filename, json) {
            if (json.success) {
                if (json.IsSignature) {
                    alert("IN");
                }
...
```

How can I parse Json response to make it work in IE:

sample response:

```
{"PackageErrorType":0,"PackageId":"AGI-MM-CFG-NUB-2.0.1.2.2","SignatureMatch":false,"IsSignature":false,"success":true}
```

Comment: Can I see the script too? it should work with your response....

Comment: please see added code in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the text/plain returned by the server using the `$.parseJSON` method:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(textReturnedByServer);
if (json.success) {
    if (json.IsSignature) {
        alert("IN");
    }
}
```

Of course you should do this only for the legacy browsers that do not support HTML5 File API such as Internet Explorer.

Comment: when I parse it i get null in json variable.  this is what I see in IE's console:  [FineUploader] converting iframe's innerHTML to JSON 
 [FineUploader] innerHTML = <pre>{"PackageErrorType":0,"PackageId":"AGI-MM-GM-RTB-2.0.3.1.4","SignatureMatch":false,"IsSignature":false,"success":true}</pre>  Could it be because of the <PRE> tag?? if so how do I parse it?

Comment: Yes, it's because of the pre tag. You could filter it out.