# IE10/IE11 at compatibility mode Mode 8 hangs wenn upload file with jquery.fileupload.js (9.5.2)

Tags: jquery, file-upload, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, freeze

we have to use IE10/IE11 in compatibility mode IE 8 to support legacy online sites which use (open in their context -> Iframe) a new html5-applications (jquery, angular). This html5 application uses jquery.fileupload.js (version 9.5.2) which works fine for IE8/9 in mode 8 and 10 and 11 and their origin mode but fails if we (and we have to) switch IE 10 or 11 to mode 8. The new opened page (htnml5) hangs (only the current tab) and the user can not use the cuerrent site any more and has to restart IE. We have alreday deeply debugged the jquery code  until form.submit() but then we lost the track an could not find the point where the problem is located. It seems that the needed iframe for the response is not created so that the neccesary event "onloaded" is not created and the processing is stopped (cpu is at 0 costs).

Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning a json object just add the content type. For instance:

```
return Json(new{id = "1"}, "text/html");
```

This also solves when you try to get the response and IE9 asks to download.

See [IE9 JSON Data "do you want to open or save this file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388893/ie9-json-data-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file) for a complete answer.